# how display another object of data in a Templates

Tags: php, silverstripe

this is Area class function

```
        public function findLatestReport()
    {
        $getReport = Report::get()->filter('AreaID',$this->ID)
            ->sort('Date ASC')->first();
        return $getReport;
    }
```

This is Report class function

```
    public function getWeatherStatus()
    {
        return $this->Fields()->filter('Name', 'Weather Status')->first();
    }
```

is there any way to display 'area' template of WeatherStatus details.??

```
<% loop $findLatestReport %>
        {$WeatherStatus}
<% end_loop %>
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use `with`, rather than `loop`, as you're returning a single DataObject (with `->first()`) rather than a list. Then you should be able to access `$WeatherStatus`:

```
<% with $findLatestReport %>
    {$WeatherStatus}
<% end_with %>
```